# Calling selenium webdriver python function from another file

Tags: python, function, class, selenium-webdriver, function-calls

I'm trying to create custom functions in selenium webdriver to perform specific operations. I need to call these functions from another file.

I tried this code first which opens the Google homepage:

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re
from selenium import webdriver

seed_url="http://www.google.com"
class test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "https://www.google.com/")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_urlfunctions(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel = webdriver.Firefox()
        sel.get(seed_url)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Next I tried to create a function to open a URL (This is a very basic function, I'll be doing more operation such as storing the html source for the webpage in the future) :

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re
from selenium import webdriver

seed_url="http://www.google.com"
class test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "https://www.google.com/")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_urlfunctions(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel = webdriver.Firefox()

        def open_url(url):
            sel.get(url)

        open_url(seed_url)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I need to call the open_url function from another file. How should I import the files ? I'm new to class/functions concepts of python. Please help.

Thanks,
Sly

Comment: Why do you need to have `open_url` as a separate function?  It is trivial: `sel.get(url)`.

Comment: Later I want to store the html source and do some more functions. Just need to know the basic functioning first.

Comment: Although your code is dealing mostly with Selenium, the question at hand has nothing to with it. You should consider rephrasing the whole thing into a simple question of how to call a function in one file from a function in another file, in Python.

Comment: I know how to call a function, but over here when I call the function from another file I get an 'socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused' error.